# Error while making Spline

Tags: qt

I am trying to make spline in qt but while compiling I am getting error

```
 error: QChart: No such file or directory
 #include <QChart>
```

Please guide me how to solve the problem.

Comment: AFAIK QChart is an addon only available in Qt Enterprise. Do you have it?

Comment: No I dont have it. :( So it means I cant use it with qtCreater?

Comment: You can't use Enterprise Addons with the OpenSource Qt. No matter which IDE you use. But you can take a look at qwt. It is a free addon providing charts. I don't know QChart so I can't tell if they're anything alike.